# Image sequence animation with multiple animationDuration iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I can load some `UIImage` from an array in an `UIImaheView` with `animationImages` & `startAnimating` properties, with a fixed **`animationDuration`**.

Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0001.png", @"0002.png", @"0003.png", @"0004.png", @"0005.png", @"0006.png", @"0007.png", @"0008.png", @"0009.png", @"0010.png", @"0011.png", @"0012.png", @"0013.png", @"0014.png", @"0015.png", @"0016.png", @"0017.png", @"0018.png", @"0019.png", @"0020.png", nil];


    self.imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < [imageNamesArray count]; i++)
    {
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }

    self.imageView.animationImages = imageArray;
    self.imageView.animationDuration = 0.04;
    self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [imageView startAnimating];
}
```

But, I want to load those `UIImage` in that same `UIImageView` with different `animationDuration`. Let me explain what I mean. I have an array named `imageNamesArray` which contains 20 different image names. Now, I want to have an another array which will contain 20 different time duration.

```
self.durationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"0.5", @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.5",  @"0.4",  @"0.9",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.6",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.8",  @"0.4",  @"0.4",  @"0.3",  @"0.4", nil];
```

And I want to show each image from that `imageArray` in that `UIImageView` according to the time duration of `durationArray`. How can I implement that. Can I use `NSTimer` to do the job? If any have solution please share with me. A lot of thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you need to use some timing method (could be an NSTimer) to display your images instead of using the animationImages approach.

Comment: @ rdelmar, Thank you Sir for your comment. Yes, I also think so. But, here I actually working on some emoticons. So, do you think using `NSTimer` will be perfect for that? I am talking about the memory issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, I wrote it just now, if there are errors please let me know.

```
-(void)refreshTimer
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageNamesArray objectAtIndex:count]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(refreshTimer) withObject:nil afterDelay:[[self.durationArray objectAtIndex:count] doubleValue]];
    count++;
}
```

count here is an int. From your Viewdidload call this method once

```
[self refreshTimer];
```

Comment: A lot of thanks for your comment. Yes, It is working. Just I have to put a `if else` condition in the method and run the method according to the number of my arrays elements.
I am working on `emoticons`. Do you think `performSelector` will perform the same performance like `animationDuration`?

Comment: There is no performance issue with performSelector. You can use it without problem. If the answer is correct can you please select the answer as the correct answer?

Comment: It is working, If i want to show only one animation. But what if I want to use multiple set of array for multiple animation. What I mean is, say I have 3 array for image names, and 2 array for their according duration. How can i continuously show them in this method?? Do you have any idea?